# Getting exception: org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am an android beginner please do the needful help over this.

```
try {
 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
 // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
  DataFish fishData = new DataFish();
  fishData.nonce = json_data.getString("nonce");
  fishData.iUserId = json_data.getString("iUserId");
  fishData.timestamp = json_data.getString("timestamp");
  fishData.token = json_data.getString("token");

  data.add(fishData);
 }

 // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
 mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
 mAdapter = new AdapterFish(PostActivity.this, data);
 mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
 mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(PostActivity.this));

} 
catch (JSONException e) {
 Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I have converted it to JSONArray still I am getting

> org.json.JSONException: Value {"code":"0","message":"Access denied,
>   invalid user reference"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be
>   converted to JSONArray.

Comment: Post your JSON data.

Comment: First check your code is o or 1. if code 1 to get array value

Comment: Use code key integer

Comment: I have posted in JSON data in doinbackground method

Comment: No, I meant post the JSON response that you get from the server.

Comment: I am not getting any response because I am getting rg.json.JSONException: Value {"code":"0","message":"Access denied, invalid user reference"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray.

Comment: From the error, I can say that, if your credentials are wrong, you are not getting any data from the server which contains, `iUserId`, `token`, etc. in the JSON.

Comment: Please post valid your data.

Comment: First store your responce in JsonObject....after it will show you the responce..like instead of  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result); use  JSONObject jobj= new JSONObject (result);

Comment: I want to post {
   "nonce" : "G9Ivek",
  "iUserId" : "477",
  "timestamp" : "20160614060439",
      
} like this data where should I write this?

Comment: what is the result here? you want to get the responce or send json array to server..??

Comment: Your response is object not a array

Comment: I want to send { "nonce" : "G9Ivek", "iUserId" : "477", "timestamp" : "20160614060439" } to php server

Comment: Please tell me what to do..

Comment: Your data display in app or send to server?

Comment: @RujutaDeshpande what u get in "result" when u get response from server ?? this check by Log.

Answer (score 0):

TRY it.

```
JSONArray alldata = new JSONArray();

for(your codition to get data for how many array items in loop){
JSONObject all = new JSONObject(); 
all.put("nonce", "G9Ivek");
all.put("iUserId", "477");
all.put("timestamp","20160614060439");
alldata.put(all);
```

}

and send alldata to server.

Hope this will help you..Let me know..

For send to server

```
JSONObject objMainList = new JSONObject();
objMainList.put("ALLDETAILS", alldata);
```

For bind date with api url in ASYNC TASK DOINBACKGROUND()

```
Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    param.put("access_code", access_code);
                    param.put("auth_token", auth_token);
                    param.put("data", objMainList.toString());

                    try {
                        HttpUtility.sendPostRequest(Config.Submit_Answer, param);
                        String response = HttpUtility.readMultipleLinesRespone();
                        json = new JSONObject(response);
                        HttpUtility.disconnect();

} catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
```

Comment: What to write to send alldata to server?

Comment: please follow the above answer to send to server ..and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an JSONArray object. It is an JSONObject, you can not parse it to JSONArray. For more reference you can check [it here](http://www.json.org/).